# javascript onclick method only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

when I click `Button` the first time `func1` works well, but when I click it again it doesn't work.

Even the `alert('func1')` does not work

What am I doing wrong?

```js
function func2(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "url2",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id: id,
        },
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                //do something
            } else {
                //do something
            }
        },
        complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, status) {
            //
        }
    });
}

function func1(id) {
    alert('func1');
    var flag = false;
    $.ajax({
        url: "url1",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id: id,
        },
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == 'false') {
                //do something
                flag = true;
            }
        },
    });

    if (flag) {
        func2(id);
    }
}
```

```html
<a id="xx_1" onclick="func1(1);">Button</a>
<a id="xx_2" onclick="func1(2);">Button</a>
.... 
<a id="xx_n" onclick="func1(n);">Button</a>
```

Comment: can you show your button onlclick code

Comment: func1() is the onclick code

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in your console?

Comment: Two or more clicks work for me. Also `authorized is undefined`

Comment: In `if(authorized){ func2(id); }` code, authorized is a global variable? I think that is the problem, code runs till that run, cannot find this variable so stops and do not run anymore

Comment: open your browser console and check for errors, i suspect the url is not valid

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in func1 "complete: function(){}" after success

```
function func1(id) {alert('func1');
    var flag = false;
    $.ajax({
        url : "url1",
        type : "POST",
        data:{
            id : id,
        },
       cache : false,
       async : false,
       dataType : 'json',
       success : function(data) {
            if(data.status == 'false') {
                //do something
                flag = true;
            } 
       },
       complete: function(){}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of that remove the on click and do it in jquery as follows, this will register the event for your button.

```
$(document).on('click', '#YOUR_BTN_ID', function({
    var flag = false;
    $.ajax({
        url : "url1",
        type : "POST",
        data:{
            id : id,
        },
       cache : false,
       async : false,
       dataType : 'json',
       success : function(data) {
            if(data.status == 'false') {
                //do something
                flag = true;
            } 
       },
       complete: function(){}
    })});
```

Comment: Because the <a> is one of the list reading from database, and their id will be different, so I think I can not use this method

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery to unAttach the onclick event then attach it

```
$(document).off.on('click', 'ButtonId', func1(1));
```

repeat the above line in the `Func1` itself